# Stored Procedure that creates a table from parameters given

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and am trying to create procedure that takes in two parameters, the table name t char(20), and the primary key p char(20), and creates a table from them. However when I call my procedure it creates the table t instead of the value t is holding. I am very new to SQL so I apologize if this is very simple.

Here is my code:

```
Create Procedure createTable(IN t char(20), IN d char(20)) 
    create table t(d char(20))
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
delimiter $$

Create Procedure createTable (
    IN in_t varchar(20),
    IN in_d varchar(20)
) 
begin
    set @sql = 'create table [t] ([d] char(20))';

    set @sql = replace(replace(@sql, '[d]', in_d), '[t]', in_t);

    prepare stmt from @sql;

    execute stmt;
end;

delimiter ;
```

By the way, I would never have the `id` be a character string.  An auto-increment id seems much more reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much I will do some reading on Dynamic SQL! And now that you say that, I can see why I should have an auto-incrementing id, Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Could you tell me why you put in_ in front of the variables?

Comment: To distinguish function parameters from columns in the table.

Comment: Another way:  Use `CONCAT()` instead of `REPLACE()`.